# Manjaro Linux Installer cannot find a partition to install

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, installation, manjaro

I recently started trying to install Manjaro Linux, but the installer could not find a partition to install. I opened GParted and THE ONLY PARTITION it found was my USB drive i was booting from. I have 2 drives (A NVMe which has Windows on it, and a Sata which I used to install PopOS before.) The drives should be properly set in the computer, and the computer will not find it. I am trying to install it, and it says "There are no partitions available." What do i do?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you trying to install a non-UEFI OS on an UEFI system?   Run it in a virtual machine.